# Syntax Error in call to print

Tags: python

I am currently coding a slot-like game, and everything seems to work besides this one thing:

```
  File "/Users/r/Desktop/Game.py", line 36
    print(one, end = " ")
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you are running Python3? In Python 2 you can `from __future__ import print_function` to get Python3's `print` function

Comment: If you are using python 2.x, the `print` is not a function. You need to switch to python 3.x, or type `from future import print_function` to be able to use `print()` as it is in python 3.x

Comment: If my answer helped would you mind giving it the checkmark?

Answer (score -2):

Are you trying to pass a Boolean for the second parameter to `print`?

In that case you want `print(one, end == ' ')`

Comment: Oh, thank you. This did indeed work.